# Passing char into a method with an int parameter

Tags: java, type-conversion

The output from the following code is `123` because `substring` takes from beginIndex to EndIndex - 1.   However, I am surprised how `char` here is understood as 3 (int) because `substring` take two ints.  What is the concept behind this?

```
String x = "12345";
char a = 3;
x = x.substring(0, a);
System.out.println(x);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This goes all the way back to [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29), where `char` is in essence a narrow integer type and gets implicitly converted to `int` whenever necessary.

In Java, this is technically known as a "widening primitive conversion", and is covered in [section 5.1.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Comment: +1 .. It boils down to not thinking of a `char` as a letter or character, but instead as a piece of data that the computer is able to map to a letter or character. Then, to facilitate this process, we've made some shortcuts to let us directly assign letters or characters to `char`s (like `char c = 'x';` just means "A piece of data represented by variable c is the value that maps to the character 'x'." The variable 'c' is no more a letter than any other piece of data in the system.)

Answer (score 3):

Others already explainted why it works but note that it is bad practice to use char variables for indices, since they have different associated semantics and thus it is confusing to use a char as an index.

Use chars only to store character data and probably better: try to avoid char altogether, since they are not even wide enough to store every character (see Unicode and code point discussion). Use int to store character code points instead.

Answer (score 0):

so substring's function declaration looks like substring(int startIndex, int endIndex).
Now when you pass char it is automatically promoted to integer (endIndex) and hence treated as int.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at section [5.1.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.2), where it discusses widening conversions.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as implicit casting. The same occurs if you assign an int value to a double.
Quick example

```
    double d = 1;
```

1 is an `int` but it is implicitly cast to `double` (1.0).

Answer (score 0):

In `char a = 3;`, you could think of it as storing `0011`, the binary value of 3. The char '3' is not actually being stored: If you tried treating is a char, you would not get `3`. But if you did

`char a = '3';`

Now you're storing the char 3, an ascii value of 51, and if you tried using it as in int, you would get 51.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is because `char` is a subtype of `int`.

To determine whether `substring(int,int)` is applicable to argument `(int,char)`, we first try [15.12.2.2 Phase 1: Identify Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Subtyping](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.2), we need to test whether `char` is a subtype of `int`. [Per 4.10.1 Subtyping among Primitive Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.1), it is.

Then, to assign the `char` argument to the `int` parameter, per [15.12.4.5 Create Frame, Synchronize, Transfer Control](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.4.5), we apply [5.3 Method Invocation Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#12687), which converts `char` to `int`, per [5.1.2 Widening Primitive Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#25214)

Answer (score 0):

This is the concept of implicit and explicit casting.
the char is of small data type then the integer so when pass character as a value then it is auto-convert the char value into int value.

```
public static void age (int  num){
        System.out.println(num);
   }
           char character = '2';
            age(character); output is 50.
```

The character form '0' to '9'  print values 48 to 57