# Why does concatenated characters print a number?

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
   public class Go {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println("G" + "o");
      System.out.println('G' + 'o');
     }
   }
```

And this is compile result;

```
  Go
  182
```

Why my output contain a number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java int and char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931862/java-int-and-char)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the second case it adds the [unicode](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) codes of the two characters (G - 71 and o - 111) and prints the sum. This is because `char` is considered as a numeric type, so the `+` operator is the usual summation in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`+` operator with character constant `'G' + 'o'` prints addition of charCode and [string concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) with `"G" + "o"` will prints `Go`.

Answer (score 2):

The plus in Java adds two numbers, unless one of the summands is a String, in which case it does string concatenation.

In your second case, you don't have Strings (you have `char`, and their Unicode code points will be added).

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("G" + "o");
  System.out.println('G' + 'o');
```

First one + is acted as a concat operater and concat the two strings. But in 2nd case it acts as an addition operator and adds the ASCII (or you cane say UNICODE) values of those two characters.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931862/java-int-and-char) previous SO question should shed some light on the subject, in your case you basically end up adding their ASCII values (71 for G) + (111 for o) = 182, you can check the values [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

You will have to use the [`String.valueOf(char c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%29) to convert that character back to a string.

Answer (score 0):

**+** is always use for `sum`(purpose of adding two numbers) if it's number except `String` and if it is `String` then use for concatenation purpose of two `String`.

**and we know that char in java is always represent a numeric**.

that's why in your case it actually computes the sum of two numbers as `(71+111)=182` and not concatenation of characters as `g`+`o`=`go`

If you change one of them as `String` then it'll concatenate the two
such as     `System.out.println('G' + "o")` 
it will print `Go` as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The "+" operator is defined for both `int` and `String`:

```
int + int = int

String + String = String
```

When adding char + char, the best match will be :

```
(char->int) + (char->int) = int
```

But `""+'a'+'b'` will give you `ab`:

```
( (String) + (char->String) ) + (char->String) = String
```