# Java programming - My username displays integers when I want characters. Why?

Tags: java, string

Here's a copy of my code. It's very simple, and all I'm trying to do is get the first initial of my first name, first initial of my middle name, and my full last name. For some reason the output is "154Wiggs"

Here's the code:

```
public class StringPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fName = "Landon";
        String mName = "Neal";
        String lName = "Wiggs";

        String userName = (fName.charAt(0) + mName.charAt(0) + lName);

        System.out.println (userName);          
    }    
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help, this is my first time here and I'm in beginning Java. I plan to come back and ask a lot more questions..thanks again!

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: I am expecting "LNWiggs" - I was thinking the charAt(0) would select the first character in the string?

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085351/why-java-character-print-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `charAt` method returns a `char` type, which represents a character, but is interpreted as a 16-bit number in some contexts.

When you add two of these together, you (unsurprisingly) get a number, and Java (perhaps surprisingly) promotes this number to the `int` type, so it now behaves differently from the original chars.

```
System.out.println(fName.charAt(0));  // L

System.out.println(0 + fName.charAt(0)); // 76


System.out.println(mName.charAt(0));  // N

System.out.println(0 + fName.charAt(0)); // 78


int sum= fName.charAt(0) + mName.charAt(0); // an int, not a char

System.out.println(sum); // 154
```

However, when you "add" a number to a String, Java coerces it (converts it) into a String.

Instead of `charAt(0)`, you need to use `substring(0,1)` and so on so that you are working uniformly with Strings.

Alternatively, use

```
String userName = (fName.charAt(0) + "" + mName.charAt(0) + lName);
```

or add parentheses:

```
String userName = (fName.charAt(0) + (mName.charAt(0) + lName));
```

to prevent the two chars from being added together and thus converted to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

String.charAt() returns a `char`. When you sum two chars you get a number.

You can do the following:

```
String userName = (fName.charAt(0) + "" + mName.charAt(0) + "" + lName);
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.charAt` returns a `char` which is an integral type: you can do math with it.  Adding two `char`s will not concatenate them but add the numeric values (their Unicode code points).

While this addition is carried out, something called *promotion* takes place.  From [§ 5.6.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§ 5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

In your case, you have two operands of type `char` so we fall into the last case:  The operands are converted to `int` and the `int`s are then added.  The result is: an `int`.

Now, “adding” that `int` result to a `String` will (by [a weird rule in the Java language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.4)) convert the integer to a string and concatenate it with the other operand.

If you want to concatenate the first characters of the first and middle name, I think the simplest way to go would be using `String.substring` instead.  It will return a `String`, not a `char`, so `+` will concatenate as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Let "" precede to form a String as follows, otherwise the ASCII value of characters (numbers) will be used

```
String userName = ("" +fName.charAt(0) + mName.charAt(0) + lName);
System.out.println (userName);//LNWiggs
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow and java.
In java you have two basic types of 'things' Objects and primitives, in the case of the method `String.charAt()` it returns a `char` which isn't a `String`.
 `String s = "a"` and `char c = 'a'` are not the same thing, and they behave different in subtle ways.
 When you write `String userName = (fName.charAt(0) + mName.charAt(0) + lName);` java is actually going to arithmetically add the values of the chars not concatenate their equivalent String values.

- `fName.charAt(0)` which holds the `char` symbol of 'L' has a value of 76.
- `mName.charAt(0)` holds the `char' symbol 'N' and value of 78.

  Therefore when your stement is evaluated it will add the values of the chars(76 + 78 = 154) with `lName` appended to the end. I find it usually better to avoid making any sort of computation in a `System.out.println()` statement, you wil find that things do not usually behave as expected.
   Hope i was helpful and
  I think you might find these resources helpful: [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)